# Copy one attribute to another in the same child element of a set of children in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Wow, so that's a mouthful.  I've been struggling with this as I'm still a newbie with JQuery selectors.  Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.  I have a situation where I'm selecting a sub-set of child div *(class='B')* from a parent div *(id='A')* using `.children()` and `.slice()`.  Furthermore, I need to copy the value of `longdesc` attribute of each grandchild div *(class='C')* to its div content.  I was thinking of something like below, but I don't know how to reference the correct grandchild div when trying to obtain the value of the `longdesc`.  Maybe there's a better approach to this? HELP!

**HTML:**

```html
<div id="A">
    <div class="B">
        <div class="C" longdesc="value1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="B">
        <div class="C" longdesc="value2"></div> 
    </div>
    <div class="B">
        <div class="C" longdesc="value3"></div> 
    </div>
    <div class="B">
        <div class="C" longdesc="value4"></div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```js
$start = 0;
$end = 2;

$('#A').children().slice($start, $end).find('.C').html("??value of longdesc??");
```

**Output:**

```html
<div id="A">
    <div class="B">
        <div class="C" longdesc="value1">value1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="B">
        <div class="C" longdesc="value2">value2</div> 
    </div>
    <div class="B">
        <div class="C" longdesc="value3">value3</div> 
    </div>
    <div class="B">
        <div class="C" longdesc="4"></div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [version of `.html()` that take a function as parameter](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-functionindex--oldhtml)..

```
$('#A').children().slice($start, $end+1).find('.C').html(function(){
    return $(this).attr('longdesc');
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/aaFt9/1/

---

You also need to use `$end + 1` to match the `value3` because `slice` second argument is up-to but not including it (*see [`Array.prototype.slice()` docs at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)*)

---

Additionally if that is your real html structure, you can skip the `.children()` and find the `.C` elements directly..

```
$('#A').find('.C').slice($start, $end+1).html(function(){
    return $(this).attr('longdesc');
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/aaFt9/2/

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I needed.  Much simpler than I thought.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(".C").html(function () {
    return $(this).attr("longdesc")
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/u5jwg/)**

---

**EDIT** : re-reading the question, you could try

```
var $end = 2;
$(".C").each(function (i) {
    i <= $end ? $(this).html(function () {
        return $(this).attr("longdesc")
    }) : null;
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PdHLN/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#A").find(".B").children().each(function(){
   $(this).html($(this).attr('longdesc')); 
});
```

Fitting in the [.slice()](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) should not be a problem, wherever you want.